# Como compartilhar um dicionario entre scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho um dicionario central que recebe todos arquivos jsons do meu diretório de trabalho:

```
def loaddata():
with os.scandir('Jsons/') as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.json'):
            pass
        with open(entry.path, 'r') as f:
            key = entry.name[:-5]
            value = f.read()
            center_dict[key] = json.loads(value)
```

Eu preciso que esse dicionario esteja acessível para todos os outros "arquivos.py" que tenho no diretório. Eu consigo importar funções entre esses scripts normalmente com:

`import funcao from arquivo`.

No entanto quando tento fazer o mesmo para esse dicionário

`ImportError: cannot import name 'dict_teste' from 'script'`.

O que estou fazendo por enquanto é chamando `loaddata()` para cada um dos scripts no entanto isso demora demais e acaba com o dinamismo da aplicação. Conhecem alguma maneira de transformar esse dicionario em algo que possa ser acessado para todos scripts ou alguma outra forma de lidar com o problema ?

****** edit ******

Esse dicionário central é um dicionário de instruções. Ele precisa ser lido por cada um dos scripts, no entanto, não será modificado em momento algum.

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que criar uma função que receba o dicionário como parâmetro. Depois você chama essa função no arquivo python desejado

Comment: alguma ideia de uma função que pegue esse dicionário do meu script principal e transforma ele numa variável global do meu script secundário ?

Comment: Esses scripts irão executar ao mesmo tempo? Se sim, as alterações feitas no dicionário por um devem refletir nos outros? E se dois scripts alterarem a mesma posição ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Sim, um script chama o outro.  Não faço alterações no dicionario em momento algum no código no entanto cada código precisa de uma parte especifica desse dicionario. Por exemplo o meu main.py precisa do dict_central['main'], o meu segundario.py precisa do dict_central['segundario'] ... A sua terceira pergunta eu não compreendi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um novo script chamado jsonmanager.py:

```
import json
import os

center_dict = {}

def loaddata():
    with os.scandir('Jsons/') as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.json'):
                pass
            with open(entry.path, 'r') as f:
                key = entry.name[:-5]
                value = f.read()
                center_dict[key] = json.loads(value)
```

No meu código principal adicionei:

```
from jsonmanager import loaddata

loaddata()
```

E em todos os meus outros scripts secundários tudo que eu preciso fazer é um import simples:

```
from jsonmanager import center_dict
```

Comment: Como você já está chamando `loaddata()` no corpo do módulo `json_manager.py`, significa que ele já será executado automaticamente no primeiro `from jsonmanager import center_dict` que for encontrado. Então não precisa adicionar uma chamada a `loaddata()` no seu script principal; estará rodando `loaddata()` duas vezes.

Comment: Eu fiz essa correção no meu script mas passou desapercebido aqui, obrigado pela notificação. vou editar.